# How can I avoid writing this.spinner = false so many times?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming and am trying to learn best practices. An issue I continue to encounter is repeated instructions, as exemplified in the code sample below. As you can see, I have `this.spinner = false` declared no less than three times. Surely, there is a better way?

```
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    if (response.data.error == true) {
                        this.error = true;
                        this.buttonTxt = "get BOM";
                        this.spinner = false;
                        this.message = response.data.message;
                    } else {
                        this.buttonTxt = "get BOM";
                        this.spinner = false;
                        this.bomData = response.data.bomData;
                    }
                })
                .catch((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.error = true;
                    this.spinner = false;
                    this.message = "Network or server error. Could next execute PHP.";
                    this.buttonTxt = "get BOM";
                });
```

Comment: You set it to false no matter what? Why put it in any conditionals? At most you need two. You set a lot of things over and over; maybe a method instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promise has a `.finally()` clause which will run no matter the promise resolved or rejected. You can write your `this.spinner = false;` in there once for all cases. For more information check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally)

For example

```
.then(() => {/* do whatever upon success */})
.catch( () => {/* error */})
.finally( () => this.spinner = false );
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```js
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    // common code
                     this.buttonTxt = "get BOM";
                     this.spinner = false;
                    if (response.data.error == true) {
                        this.error = true;
                        this.message = response.data.message;
                    } else {                
                        this.bomData = response.data.bomData;
                    }
                })
                .catch((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.error = true;
                    this.spinner = false;
                    this.message = "Network or server error. Could next execute PHP.";
                    this.buttonTxt = "get BOM";
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You set spinner and btnTxt in either case success or failure.

```js
                .then((response) => {
                    this.buttonTxt = "get BOM";
                    this.spinner = false;
                    this.error = true;
                    if (response.data.error === true) {
                        this.message = response.data.message;
                    } else {
                        this.bomData = response.data.bomData;
                        this.error = false;
                    }
                })
                .catch((response) => {
                    this.message = "Network or server error. Could next execute PHP.";
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are always setting the spinner to `false`, you can simply initialize it with that value to begin with. So your code would look like this:

```
// define this before chaining on .then
this.spinner = false;


// continue with your code here
.then((response) => {
 console.log(response.data);
 if (response.data.error == true) {
    this.error = true;
    this.buttonTxt = "get BOM";
    this.message = response.data.message;
 } else {
    this.buttonTxt = "get BOM";
    this.bomData = response.data.bomData;
 }
})
  .catch((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    this.error = true;
    this.message = "Network or server error. Could next execute PHP.";
    this.buttonTxt = "get BOM";
});
```

Now, you only have to set it to `true` whenever you need to.

Better yet, you can write functions that group related actions together. For instance, I see that you always have `this.error = true` and `this.buttonTxt = "get BOM"` and a dynamic `this.message` variable  together. So you could write a function like so:

```
function handleError(message) {
   this.error = true;
   this.buttonText = "get BOM";
   this.message = message;
}
```

and pass in the error message directly.

So, taking all the changes together, your code would look like this:

```
// define these before chaining on .then
this.spinner = false;

this.handleError = function handleError(message) {
   this.error = true;
   this.buttonText = "get BOM";
   this.message = message;
}

// continue with your code here
.then((response) => {
 console.log(response.data);
 if (response.data.error == true) {
    this.handleError(response.data.message)
 } else {
    this.buttonTxt = "get BOM";
    this.bomData = response.data.bomData;
 }
})
  .catch((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    this.handleError("Network or server error. Could next execute PHP.");
});
```